# HBase: how to save an object with nested fields like list of lists?

Tags: hbase

let's say i have a class Customer and it has simple fields like firstName, lastName etc. but also a list of Contacts as field and every Contact object has a list of emails and a list of telephone numbers. I already know how the HBase schema could look like with simple String fields like firstName. But I am not sure how to save the nested fields ( list of objects, each containing list of other objects or data types). 
Could any one assist me with it?

regards

**Java Classes:**

```
public class Customer{
   private String id;
   private String userName;
   private String lastName;
   private List<Address> addresses;
   private List<Contact> contacts;
   private List<Objects> objects; // list of other possible objects
}

public class Address{
   private String homeNumber;
   private String street;
   private String city;
}

public class Contact{
   private List<String> emails;
}
```

---

**HBase Schema:**

```
Table: Customer
Row Key: id
Column Family: data [columns: userName, lastName]
Column Family: address [ columns: homeNumber, street, city ]
Column Family: contact ???
```

how does it work with contacts here? Or how can I have other address entries of the List?

regards

---

How can I save a few addresses in Customer table? Put's method:

```
add(byte[] family, byte[] qualifier, byte[] value)
```

sujests I can have only one address. Ist that right? for "row1" there is the following example:

```
add("adress", "homenumber", value);
add("adress", "street", value);
add("adress", "city", value);
```

that would be one address. how do i save others for this "row1" in this manner?

regards,

Comment: You should consider to accept an answer.  Will also help your reputation ;)

Answer (score 2):

What **access patterns** you want to have for your `Customer` collection members is what should determine how you store them.

For example, do you ever have a reason to retrieve only a part of a customers address? Probably not. Then why not simply have an `address` column family containing columns whose qualifiers are the hashcodes (or some other distinctive value) of addresses and whose cells contain JSON data?

What is the access pattern for customer contacts? For these you might have a `contact` column family whose column qualifiers are contact hashcodes/IDs and cell contents are emails.

---

Here are example contents of the `address` column family for a customer that has two addresses:

column: `address:589F2AB09C`
contents: `{ "homenumber": 4, "street": "Cherry Ln", "city": "Pleasantville" }`

column: `address:FB94012AC4`
contents: `{ "homenumber": 100, "street": "Broadway", "city": "New York City" }`

The hashcode column qualifiers above are values I just made up.  Really, you should have a hash function that maps an `Address` to a `byte[]`, then use the `byte[]` as the qualifier for that `Address`. A good way to write that hash function is (1) serialize your `Address` to a `byte[]`, then (2) compute the SHA1 hash of that `byte[]` to obtain a new `byte[]`, the hashcode.

If you still don't understand what I'm saying, I think you might be in over your head trying to use HBase...

Comment: that's right. I might never want to retrieve part of an address. Are you also sujesting the same approach with haveing ids in address column family for lookup in another "address" table? also for Contacts?

Comment: i added this to the question above. Would you mind take a look?

Comment: My suggestion was that the `address` column family would contain columns whose qualifiers were hashcodes of the respective addresses, and whose cells were JSON data. For example, a customer with two addresses would have two columns, each looking something like this: column: `address:589F2AB09C` contents: `{ "homenumber": 4, "street": "Cherry Ln", "city": "Pleasantville" }`.  To do this, you'll have to have a hash function that takes a `Address` object and returns a `byte[]` hashcode.

Comment: do you mean that each row value could be a JSON data? And about the Addresses, should the hashcodes be separated with a "space" and all be put together in a byte[] to save them in hbase? like this byte[] for saving three address hashcodes: [589F2AB09C\X00459A2AB28C\X00769E2BB01]. is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Updated to include your example:

```
HBase Schema:
Table: Customer
Row Key: id [id1]
Column Family: data
   userName: [user1]
   lastName: [name1]
Column Family: address
   homeNumber: [1234]
   street: [fake st.]
   city: [anywhere, USA]
Column Family: contacts
   contactList: [con1@email.com con2@email.com]

Table: Contacts
Row Key: emails [email1@email.com]
```

If you only need to keep contacts emails, then you don't need the extra table. If you need other information about the contacts, then you use the emails (which are space delimited) as a rowkey to look up in the contacts table

How you would go about doing this really depends on what you end up doing with the data. This is the approach I would take considering that HBase doesn't really like wide tables (it decreases performance of reading if I remember correctly).

Here's what I would look into doing:

1. You need some sort of unique identifier for contacts, whether it be first_namelast_name or email or whatever.
2. I would then store those contacts in a separate table. HBase doesn't do well with too wide of tables, which is easily a problem if you have lists of lists. Plus, this makes it easier to have variable number of contacts. Put these contacts in a separate table, and you will then reference them to pull out the relevant information.
3. You then include the references in a contacts column of your customer table, where it'd be a list of the rowkeys. You would have to delimit these lists yourself, with something like semicolons, or tildes.

TL;DR separate customers and contacts into separate tables, then include a delimited list of contact rowkeys in your customers table. Then parse and pull from accordingly.

Comment: thanks very much. I have just added some concrete code exmaples to my question. Would you please describe your answer with it? regards

Comment: I just updated the top of my post to include a new schema, and how to use it. If you have any more questions about it, just le tme know!

Comment: I just made some corrections in my code. instead of "List<String> addresses" it is now "List<Address> addresses". My question is, if the customer has more than one address, can i save them all in customer table? or do I need an extra table for addresses? And class Contact definitely has more fields. So I guess it should be like: (contactList:[contact1 contact2 ...]) and each "contact" is an id. Now it should be defined what could be an id of a contact. Is it right? How many tables are we allowed to have? I might have read there are some limitations!!

Comment: You have the right idea with the contacts. And you'd apply the same idea for addresses as well (I would add another table if you have more than one field in a subclass). This is because it's a lot easier to expand/edit address information and contact information if you have an additional table to just query. You're allowed to have as many tables as you want. Right now in our cluster, we have about 15. Try not to go overboard, but you should be good with a few extra tables.

Comment: "HBase doesn't really like wide tables (it decreases performance of reading if I remember correctly)." This isn't quite right. If you're trying to scan a single column `C` in a "wide" column family `CF`, the scanner has to pass over all of the other columns in `CF`, which can be costly. But if a table has tons of column families, each containing only a few columns, you shouldn't have any problem scanning a single column.

Comment: Also, a customer has a list of addresses, which doesn't fit into the schema you've provided.

Comment: exactly, it does n't fit. Either i should link the addresses to another Table called "Address" as JGibel sujested or I could save the customer's addresses in customer's Table! I don't know how to the second approach or if I should it at all. Put's method "add(byte[] family, byte[] qualifier, byte[] value)" would be "add(address,homeNumber,1234)", add(address,street,"aStreet") etc. this would be one address. how can I save another address in this manner for the currently Row Key (currently Customer)??

Comment: i added this to the question above. Would you mind take a look?

Comment: hello, i also don't understand how to use [con1@email.com con2@email.com] as a RowKey in Contact-Table. should n't i separate the emails again? Could you explain your solution with some code. thanks for your help.